# How to force OS to free port with python

Tags: python, sockets, network-protocols

I use a port in my python program and close it,now I want to use it again.Just that port not another port.

Is there any way to force OS to free port with python?

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file 

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12349
portt = 12341               # Reserve a port for your service.

s.bind((host, portt))        # Bind to the port

s.connect((host, port))
s.close

ss = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name 
ss.bind((host, portt))

s.close
```

but the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 17, in <module>
    ss.bind((host, portt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: `s.close` is a method. you call it by `s.close()`, otherwise that just displays the infos regarding the type of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll never be able to force the OS (with any sort of reasonable effort) to release a socket.

Instead you just want to say you don't care with [`setsockopt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt)

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

This means that the option takes place at the **S**ocket **O**bject **L**evel SOCKET (as opposed to the TCP or something else) and you're setting the **S**ocket **O**ption REUSEADDR (you're telling the OS that it's OK, you really do want to listen here). And finally, you're turning the option on with `1`, rather than off (with `0`).