# "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use" when checking IP address in a loop

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using the [`whatismyip`](https://pypi.org/project/WhatIsMyIP/) package to check my IP address before I call an IP sensitive API. The code runs in a loop and I'm finding after a few iterations I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

From some searching I understand this is because `whatismyip` is trying to use its designated port before it's been freed up.

I've tried creating an MRE to replicate the error:

```
import time
import whatismyip

EXPECTED_IP = "123.123.123.123"

while True:
    current_ip_address = whatismyip.whatismyipv4()
    if current_ip_address != EXPECTED_IP:
        raise Exception
    time.sleep(0.1) # simulate accessing IP sensitive API for info A
    current_ip_address = whatismyip.whatismyipv4()
    if current_ip_address != EXPECTED_IP:
        raise Exception
    time.sleep(0.1) # simulate accessing IP sensitive API for info B
    current_ip_address = whatismyip.whatismyipv4()
    if current_ip_address != EXPECTED_IP:
        raise Exception
    time.sleep(0.1) # simulate accessing IP sensitive API for info C
```

However, annoyingly it only spits out:

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=73, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 54320)>
```

This looks related to my error but doesn't stop the code.

In the real code I've tried catching the `OSError` and retrying `whatismyip.whatismyipv4()` but this just generates the same error.

The error occurs on the last line of this block of code that I've extracted from the package:

```
SOURCE_IP = '0.0.0.0'
SOURCE_PORT = 54320

sockObj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sockObj.settimeout(2)
sockObj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sockObj.bind((SOURCE_IP, SOURCE_PORT))
```

In searching for solutions, most answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39557155/11277108), seem to recommend finding the process that uses the port and kill it. However, these don't provide any code I could include in my script. In addition to this I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23224980/11277108) which says you can't get the OS to close a socket. It then recommends implementing the same code that's already above:

```
sockObj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

I realise this isn't a perfect post because I can't replicate the error in an MRE but would anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

I'm using python 3.10.8 on MacOS 13.2.1.

Comment: If you're getting that error when you simply call the library function in a loop, it's a bug in the library.

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: It looks like MacOS implements `SO_REUSEADDR` on UDP sockets different from Linux. I suspect they only tested the code on Linux.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. Looks like you've found the issue. Here's a link to a post that explains more fully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998042/macos-so-reuseaddr-so-reuseport-not-consistent-with-linux. No solutions there though - any ideas?

Comment: Report the problem to the `whatismyip` programmer